# If the non trivial combination of n Vectors in $\mathbb R ^n$ equals 0, can I say that they span all of $\mathbb R ^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I hope I phrased the question right and I'm not asking something too silly again.

I'm reviewing and I came up with an old homework I found.
Show that the Subset S of $\mathbb R ^4$ consisting of the vectors x, y, z, w
that fulfill the equation $ 2x + 4y + 3z +7w = 0 $ are a subspace of $\mathbb R ^4$.

Now the first time I solved this I went through the motions and showed that it's closed under addition and multiplication.

But this time, having some other additional ressources under my belt, I feel like I could also say that because $ 2x + 4y + 3z +7w = 0 $ the vectors must be linearly independent (or am I drawing the wrong conclusion here? I'm afraid I am). they span all of $\mathbb R ^4$ and it follows that all vectors must stay in $\mathbb R ^4$?

Comment: This is hard to follow. If a non-trivial  linear combination of vectors is $\vec 0$ that shows that the vectors are $\textit {dependent}$ not independent.  Also, just showing that a bunch of vectors are in $\mathbb R^4$ doesn't prove that they form a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: It is also clear that this particular subspace is not all of $\mathbb R^4$.  The vector $\vec v=(1,0,0,0)$ is not in the subspace, for instance.

Comment: I think you are confusing a linear combination of components with a linear combination of vectors.

Comment: Hi, @almagest thanks, yes, I think I'm confusing something I'm not quite sure. I just thought I can arrange the vectors in a 4x4 matrix and solve in until I have the Identity = 2, 4, 3, 7

Comment: @lulu thanks. Right I see it now, I was mixing this up because I think I've written a wrong matrix equation to solve from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $2x+3y+4z+7w$ does not mean that vectors $x,y,z,$ and $w$ are linearly independent

and span $\mathbb R^4$.

For example, take $x=(2,0,0,0), y=(7,0,0,0), z=(-1,0,0,0), $ and $w=(-3,0,0,0)$.